# URL Filtering in servlet

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I want to change my application URL like:-

**This**

http://localhost:8080/My_Application/Home.do?App_TOKEN=501GwDhUPqrT4bOBH8YQFt&customAction=addStudent

**To**

http://localhost:8080/My_Application/Home.do

But I want to send the "**App_TOKEN=501GwDhUPqrT4bOBH8YQFt&customAction=addStudent"** into body header as well.

Please suggest.

Comment: for these type of requirement post is good. Do you want to replace this url in address bar?

Comment: Yes, i want to change it to address bar , but i want to send the rest of query string to the next page as well. but i want no body to see that rest of query string.

Comment: Do you want App_TOKEN to be in the msg body or header?

Comment: Any one , but this should not be visible on the Address bar.